# access to a related collection in an ember-model object via hasMany relationship

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-model

I may fundamentally be misunderstanding how to use the hasMany relationships in Ember/ember-model.

the [ember-model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model) readme has the following example

```
postJson = {
  id: 99,
  title: 'Post Title',
  body: 'Post Body',
  comments: [
    {
      id: 1,
      body: 'comment body one',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      body: 'comment body two'
    }
  ]
};

App.Post = Ember.Model.extend({
  id: Ember.attr(),
  title: Ember.attr(),
  body: Ember.attr(),
  comments: Ember.hasMany('App.Comment', {key: 'comments', embedded: true})
});

App.Comment = Ember.Model.extend({
  id: Ember.attr(),
  body: Ember.attr()
});
```

presumably, one would do the following

```
post = App.Post.create();
post.load(1, postJson);
```

given the above, now we have access to various `post` props via get (i.e. `post.get('title')`), but how to I access the comments?

`post.get('comments')` returns an object, but it is not a collection of App.Comment objects, which is what I'd expect.

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a collection object which is iterable, but not an array.  I'm working up an example with your code, I'll post it up momentarily (I'm pretty sure load is a private method and you should be using load on the model definition, then find).

```
App.Post.load(postJson); //sideloading
return App.Post.find(99);
```

http://jsbin.com/hocopoga/1/edit

Comment: ah, this pointed me in the correct direction. the other point of confusion was that in this case, 'comments' are an ember enumerable http://emberjs.com/guides/enumerables/

outlined here
http://jsbin.com/hocopoga/4/edit